# Light not effecting volumetrics

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

So I'm rendering a scene out and I'm using the world volumetrics with "volume scatter". Blender Guru has a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyLOZWevi8g&t=119s) on it. When I put a "sun" light in the scene, it doesn't effect the scene at all. Why? Is this a supposed to act this way? I know when I add a plane in with an emission material, it lights it.

Comment: Are you using cycles or eevee  andare you viewing this is material preview mode or rendered view

Comment: I'm rendering in cycles and I'm viewing it in rendered mode.

Comment: you can try increasing the strength of sun,or just deleting sun lamp and add it again and what is the density value for volume scatter node it should be low round to 0.1 and you can also try reducing color brightness for volume scatter node

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Go to the top right and make sure this little guy is enabled other wise EEVEE just uses the Material Preview Settings, with preloaded HDRIs.